# How can I code to prevent spam posts in Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I fully understand captcha, and already implemented to my app.  It's working fine so far.
Obviously, it'll be annoying if it asks you captcha code to type in every time you wanna post:(

Now I'm thinking of the way comparing current time with the time the user posed last time.
If it's Post model, and it has its created_at(Timestamp)

How can I write in my controller? I'd like to use 'before filter' checking when it does create.
and I want user to wait at least 1 min to post next post.

should it be something like this below? I'm so newbie to Rails. Please help!

```
def spam_check

 @post = Post.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
 lasttime = @post.created_at.last


end
```

Comment: As an alternative, you could use [Akismet](http://akismet.com/development/). It has libraries for ruby

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `Post` model :

```
validate :spam_check?, :on => :create

def spam_check?
   @post = Post.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id).last
   last_time = @post.created_at

   Time.now - last_time > 1.minute
end
```

Comment: You can simplify those last two lines to just `Time.now - last_time <= 1.minute`.  You don't have to explicitly return true or false.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thanks, just made that change.

Comment: oops, sorry about that. it says undefined method `last' for #<Message:0x0000000637ab58>

Comment: @sub_stantial  Does that matter that I inserted into controller instead of model? Of course I added only inside of spam_check method block.

Comment: @HUSTEN  Are you still facing any problem here?

Comment: It should be `find_all_by_user_id`. Edited the answer.

Comment: @sub_stantial Thanks it's perfect now! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS to fill some automatically fill some hidden fields in your form before send. And if someone has disabled JS then simply view the captcha.

**EDIT:** It is good idea in addition to [@sub_stantial's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13815925/1017941).